# Does calculating the mean of a categorically distributed random variable make sense?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, expected-value

Consider a random variable $X$ that can take on a value from any of $K$ possible categories, and $x_i$, $i\in 1\dots k$ occurs with probability $p_i$.

It is my understanding that this is called the "Categorical Distribution", and I think we can just calculate the mean with the usual formula: $E(X) = \sum_{i=1}^K x_i p_i$.

**Does it make sense to do so?** (calculate the mean according to  $E(X) = \sum_{i=1}^K x_i p_i$.)

- One part of me says no, because we may be using integers to represent non-numeric categories (i.e. we can change the numbers arbitrarily)
- But another part of me says yes, as long as we are using the distribution with numeric meaning for the categories

  - For example, if we had the distribution representing the probability of each side of a weighted 6-sided die (for example, a die that roll 1 with $p_1=1/3$, $p_2=p_3=1/12$ and $p_4=p_5=p_6 = 1/6$)

Also, the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorical_distribution) only has the mode, not the mean in the sidebar, which I find odd (and might mean that the mean doesn't make sense?)

- Also, there is one line on the Wikipedia page which says $E[\mathbf{x}] = \mathbf{p}$, **but I think $\mathbf{p}$ is a vector and therefore doesn't make sense to me. So maybe I am not understanding something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"$20$% apple and $80$% banana" does not make sense as a fruit, or an average value of fruit.

Categorical variables do not have numerical values. If you assign them numerical values arbitrarily, you get arbitrary "mean" calculations that have no real meaning.  Part of the definition of categorical variables is that they are not ordinal--they don't have a natural ranking, or comparison of lesser to greater, let alone having actual numerical spacing (interval data) or a proper scale with a meaningful zero (ratio data).

A mode makes sense because you can say which category came up the most, or has the highest probability in other words.  But to find a mean you have to sum things up and there is no way to add apples and orangutans.

Comment: @user106860 A die roll is discrete, not categorical.  The faces are assigned numerical values unambiguously.